# Using a motor driver such as the L298N with only one GPIO pin

Tags: gpio, dc-motor

I am currently working on a project that requires many different motors to be powered by a raspberrypi. Common drivers like the L298N use two gpio pins to drive a single motor in a direction, the direction is specified by setting one of the two pin states to HIGH. I want to know if it's possible to only use one pin for this purpose, i.e. setting a gpio pin to HIGH equals pin1=HIGH and pin2=LOW and setting it to low equals pin1=LOW and pin2=HIGH.

Comment: Ah, D-Flip Flop is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop

Comment: So you want the motors to be running full speed ALL the time?  You just want to select run clockwise or run counterclockwise.

Comment: @joan yes i always want one of the pins to be high, would this chip do  the thing I want? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32999912986.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.169b7e2070yNHj&s=p&ad_pvid=202007050151462005350589779760005132092_1&algo_pvid=c35b812d-a27b-4980-b009-5dea07453d73&algo_expid=c35b812d-a27b-4980-b009-5dea07453d73-4&btsid=0b0a0ac215939391064375348e6033&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: Possibly.  I'd be tempted to use a port expander such as the I2C MCP23017.  You can hook up 8 for 128 extra GPIO so sidelining the problem.  If you do go the 74HC route make sure you can connect the chip.  A DIL package will just plug in to a breadboard.  The linked chip would be hard to use unless you are very good at soldering.

Answer (score 1):

Use a MUX or logic gate and create a function that does two things while gpio reacts differently. This way you can do that.

Comment: you mean something like this? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10000279642184.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.74f6538csWFpv2&algo_pvid=a59081a7-0e8b-4af5-82b6-0aa837609b34&algo_expid=a59081a7-0e8b-4af5-82b6-0aa837609b34-0&btsid=0b0a182b15939326916234053eab20&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: @Yes You can use something like this. But I think there better chip-set

Comment: do you maybe know a place to buy one?

Comment: @Yes if youy are leaving near China try Ali. Your nearest Store can be a place to search